# "Я сделаю всё что угодно чтобы провести с тобой хотя бы секунду" — пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Жить научился, а пунктуации нет. Правильно ли я написал: "Я сделаю всё что угодно чтобы провести с тобой хотя бы секунду"?

Answer (score 1):

Грамота.ру часто вынуждена отвечать на этот вопрос - о "всё(,) что угодно".

Мне удалось найти один развёрнутый ответ, см.:

**[Вопрос № 292687](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=292687)**

> С русским языком может произойти всё, что угодно: перестройка,
>   преображение, превращение, — но только не вымирание. Здравствуйте.
>   Многие из Ваших ответов по выражению "всё что угодно" - пишется без
>   запятой в значении "абсолютно всё". Строчка выше - из Тотального
>   диктанта прошлых годов. Почему в нём это выражение с запятой? Разве у
>   этого выражения здесь не то же самое значение?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Экспертный совет Тотального диктанта в 2010 году принимал как
>   допустимые оба варианта (и с запятой, и без нее) и комментировал эту
>   пунктограмму так: «*Все что угодно* – запятую можно ставить и не
>   ставить. Формально и исторически *что угодно* – это придаточное
>   предложение (поэтому можно поставить запятую), но оно уже превратилось
>   в устойчивое выражение (=разное, непредсказуемое, поэтому запятую
>   можно не ставить).
>
> Национальный корпус русского языка показывает разные варианты
>   пунктуации при этом обороте. Во всех текстах Стругацких из
>   Национального корпуса запятая стоит. Но в печатных изданиях Стругацких
>   встретился пример без запятой».

---

И далее - Словарь-справочник по пунктуации на Академике:

**[ВСЁ(,) ЧТО УГОДНО](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/168/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91%28%2C%29_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE_%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE)**

> Цельное по смыслу выражение. В сочетании «всё что угодно» между
>   словами «всё» и «что» знак препинания, как правило, не ставится.
>
> Однако в художественной литературе можно встретить примеры постановки
>   запятой между частями выражения «всё что угодно»: *Когда человеку
>   говорят, что он – тонкий и чуткий человек, то он, конечно, готов
>   понять всё, что угодно.* Ф. Сологуб, Дама в узлах. *К несчастью, в
>   гостинице нашлось всё, что угодно, кроме того, что спрашивал
>   проезжающий.* Д. Григорович, Капельмейстер Сусликов.
>
> ---

Необходима запятая перед "чтобы", как уже ответил Серж: она отделяет главное предложение от придаточного.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна перед союзом "чтобы".

Answer (score 0):

**По поводу "всё что угодно"**.

Думаю, что **есть смысл писать это выражение по-разному, и это зависит от степени его слитности,** что определяется по контексту.

Сделаю что угодно — сделаю всё возможное: здесь сочетание имеет значение одного слова.

Готов понять всё, что угодно — всё, что ему говорят: в этом случае сочетание делится на части.

Также: в гостинице нашлось всё, что (душе) угодно. В роли подлежащего выступает скорее местоимение всё (без оборота).