«Всё что на уме» — запятая
Нужна ли запятая?
(Контекст: ...спокойно высказать главному боссу все, что на уме.)

Желательно приводить предложение полностью,  а не его концовку.  Или хотя бы основную структуру предложения.

Странно все-таки первую часть предложения считать контекстом, так что приходится додумывать все предложение.

✦ [Я могу; можно; есть возможность...] спокойно высказать главному боссу всё, что на уме.
Это сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором и главная (первая), и придаточная части являются неполными предложениями. В этом случае, как и в обычном СПП, перед "что" ставится запятая.
Всё что на уме цельным по смыслу выражением не является.
• Из книги Н. Н. Берберовой "Железная женщина" (он — Герберт Джордж Уэллс):

«Когда-то возможно было товарищеское отношение [двух любовников], – писал он, раздраженный „современной женщиной", – можно было смеяться вместе, свободно высказывать все, что на уме, получать и давать дружескую помощь. Теперь этого нет: с женщиной живешь, как с врагом, как с доносчиком».

• Есть тип людей, которые независимо от ситуации обязательно выскажут все, что на уме... (Карл Уве Кнаусгор. Моя борьба. Книга вторая. Любовь).
Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения

Альтернативное мнение
Ответ принят, и я, пожалуй, с решением соглашусь: да, запятая ставится.
Но я категорически не согласна с объяснением, так как различить СПП и устойчивые  выражения ПО СПИСКУ у Розенталя не всегда получится, а один и тот же речевой оборот может быть устойчивым или входить в СПП.
Я  использую интонационный анализ, проверяя структуру предложения: вписывается оборот в простое предложение или нет. Как остальные участники решают такие задачи, я плохо представляю. Неужели действительно по списку? А результат хорошо виден: постоянные споры, сомнения и разные решения.
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/481164/Что-на-ум-придет-может-быть-устойчивым-сочетанием
Тема сложная и часто обсуждалась на форуме, например:
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435607/Я-сделаю-всё-что-угодно-чтобы-провести-с-тобой-хотя-бы-секунду-пунктуация/435621#435621
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471855/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-где-во-фразе-стой-где-стоишь/
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
Не всем понятно сказанное, тогда расскажу подробнее. Розенталь рассматривает тематику устойчивых выражений и дает примеры. Но фактически любой оборот может обособляться или нет в зависимости от структуры предложения, поэтому не стоит додумывать за автора то, что было в его предложении. (Приводить предложение нужно полностью. Странно, что не все с этим согласны.)
Основной ориентир в этих задачах — оборот в значении и в позиции одного слова. При наличии местоимений то, всё придаточное сложнее оформить в виде оборота, но все-так возможно.
Поэтому недостаточно написать: Всё что на уме цельным по смыслу выражением не является. По смыслу как раз является: ...спокойно высказать главному боссу любое свое мнение. Здесь проблема в структуре, а не в семантике. Собственно говоря, сам вопрос возникает из-за того, что пользователи чувствуют это обобщение (любую мысль), поэтому и сомневаются.
Пример с аналогичной семантикой:
– Если московиты будут вас о чем-то спрашивать, отвечайте что взбредет в голову, – напутствовал Бромли окоченевшую барышню. – Переводчик – человек наш, он переведет как должно.
Это реальный текст с устойчивыми оборотами и значением одного слова.
