"Что на ум придет" может быть устойчивым сочетанием?
Вот текст:
Сказать что на ум придет? Мало ли что на ум придет так все и говорить? Ведь говорят  же у дурака что на уме, то и на гумне.
Как правильно поставить знаки и объяснить их?  Хотелось бы еще, чтобы выразительно звучало.
Мне кажется, что здесь есть устойчивые сочетания, но я не уверена.
Спасибо.
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
(1) Вот еще пример в тему, альбом: Все что попало (нет запятой). https://ok.ru/music/album/122946808423290
(2) Или: Я могу сказать ему все что угодно (= любую мысль). Но почему-то: Я могу сказать ему все, что ну ум пришло.
(3) № 200013. Нужна ли запятая: "то, что надо" или "то что надо"? Спасибо за ответ. ОТВЕТ Пунктуация зависит от контекста, в значении «хороший, самый лучший» корректно: то что надо.
(4) Но почему-то: Здесь есть все, что надо (= нужное). Кстати, есть магазин с таким названием (без запятой).
Как же отличить СПП от устойчивого сочетания, есть какие-нибудь  четкие рекомендации? Устойчивое сочетание в значении одного слова — это у Розенталя. Но даже это не срабатывает)  Забавно!
